# What is limitations for ElasticSearch data types?

Tags: string, indexing, elasticsearch, lucene, limit

[Here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html) is a list of data types we can use in ElasticSearch to store the information.

But I couldn't find a link that mentions data time limitations. For example, how many characters can a String field be? Is it the same as java limitations (i.e. Integer.MAX_VALUE or 2^31-1 or about 2 billion for String)?

Since ElasticSearch uses tree structures to store information, I thought there might be limitations, as most of the RDBMS have strict limitations on data types.

Note: My question is regardless of memory limitations of the system. If I have enough memory to create a very large string, can I index and store it with ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about Elasticsearch-specific limitations, but Lucene's limitations are listed in the [Javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene40/package-summary.html#Limitations):

> Lucene's current implementation uses a Java int to hold the term
>   index, which means the maximum number of unique terms in any single
>   index segment is ~2.1 billion times the term index interval (default
>   128) = ~274 billion. This is technically not a limitation of the index
>   file format, just of Lucene's current implementation.
>
> Similarly, Lucene uses a Java int to refer to document numbers, and
>   the index file format uses an Int32 on-disk to store document numbers.
>   This is a limitation of both the index file format and the current
>   implementation. Eventually these should be replaced with either UInt64
>   values, or better yet, VInt values which have no limit.

Comment: Smart to look into Lucene instead of ElasticSearch, but I'm still more willing to find some documentation about ElasticSearch itself.